# InStr function VBA: trouble comparing file name with text object

Tags: vba, ms-word

**General Background:**

I am trying to iterate through lines of text from Word document, where each line is a unique sample name (e.g. *Sample1*, *Sample2*, *Sample3*) and then insert images from a specific folder which contain the sample name in their file name (e.g. *Sample1 a.png*, *Sample1 b.png*, *Sample2 xyz.png*, *Sample3 xxx.png*).

**Example of Code I'm Using:**

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Set MySource = fso.GetFolder("C:\Test\")
numParas = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

counter = 0
While counter < numParas
    counter = counter + 1
    sampleName = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(counter).Range.Text
    For Each File In MySource.Files
        If InStr(File.Name, sampleName) > 0 Then 
            ' Insert script here to insert pictures
            MsgBox ("File found")
        End If
    Next File
Wend
```

**Questions /Problems:**

- I can't get `InStr` to work when I comapre File.Name with sampleName (a Range.Text object).
- However, it does work if I use `If InStr(File.Name, "Sample1") > 0 Then` instead of `If InStr(File.Name, sampleName) > 0 Then`; though this does not allow me to iterate through many sample names.

**Other option for adding files from a folder:**

This thread ([Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)) shows quicker ways of looping through files in a folder. I tried using `Dir` with the following code:

```
Dim StrFile As String
Dim FolderStr As String

numParas = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
counter = 0
While counter < numParas
    counter = counter + 1
    sampleName = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(counter).Range.Text
    FolderStr = "C:\Test\*" + sampleName + "*.png"
    MsgBox (FolderStr) 'First message box
    StrFile = Dir("C:\Test\*" + sampleName + "*.png")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        ' Insert script here to insert pictures
        MsgBox ("File found")
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
Wend
```

**Questions/problems:**

- I have trouble creating Dir object iteratively as I can't concatenate the `sampleName` text object with strings.

For example, in the first message box in the script above I get the following output, with the file address on two separate lines instead of one string.

```
C:\Test\*Sample1
*.png
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare two items `File.Name` and `sampleName` using `inStr` you forget that `Samplename` is a text from paragraph which includes `paragraph ending mark`. You need to cut the last characters in any way, like:

```
sampleName = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(counter).Range.Text
sampleName = Left(sampleName, Len(sampleName) - 1)   'this new line removes paragraph ending mark
```